# Visual Studio Code run code in the same terminal

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

I didn't find the answer on Internet so I'm asking here.
I'm actually dev on Visual Studio Code some language like Python for example.
If I'm running the code, it's always opening a new terminal so I can have faster a lot of terminal opened and it's a pain to close them every time.
It is possible to run the code in the current terminal opened without write my self "python filename" ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to create a `tasks.json` file for VSCode to run a Python task in the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a project in VSCode as a task, all you need to do is create a `.vscode/tasks.json` file like so. The following task will open in the integrated terminal:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run shell command",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo 'Hello world!'",
            "group": "test",
            "presentation": {
                "panel": "shared", 
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Key focus to running in the same terminal is the `"panel": "shared"` line. This runs the command in the same terminal.

> Note: this task is untested as I do not have access to a VSCode instance at the moment.

[Here is some more information on VSCode tasks.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)
[Here is a Python task tutorial by VSCode.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)
[More information on task output behaviour.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior)

Answer (score -2):

Here my task file for anyone wants to launch a python file easier :

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run Script",
            "command": "python",
            "presentation": {
                "panel": "shared",
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true
            },
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Use the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+B for build the task and do the same shortcut when you want to rebuild :)