# How to run the selection in VSCode in the active (IPython) terminal instead of creating a new terminal every time?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I would like to execute the selection in VSCode (Shift + Enter) in my current (ipython) terminal. Instead the shortcut creates a new terminal every time and don't run the selection in the active (ipython) terminal. Which setting do I have to change to adjust this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code run code in the same terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125120/visual-studio-code-run-code-in-the-same-terminal)

Comment: Hello blarg, it tells me that it is an unknown configuration setting. My initial intention was to run selections in an active ipython terminal. I have already tried the highest scored answers I was able to find like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615414/how-to-set-ipython-jupyter-as-the-default-python-terminal-for-vscode

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly? Your steps, the results, etc.

Comment: Of course. In VSCode "Shift + Enter" run a code selection from the editor in the console in a python environment. If I create a new console and type "ipython" to create a new ipython environment, I would like to run a selection from the editor in this console with the ipython environment activated. Currently VSCode switches to the active terminal with the python environment or creates a new terminal with a python environment. I have already searched the options and tried some other methods from othter questions from stackoverflow. And since I have not managed to get this to work.

Comment: You type ipython in the powershell terminal to activate the window, but vscode has its own program flow. You use `shift+enter` to execute the selected line, and vscode will still create a new python window for execution according to its own process.

Comment: So all in all you are telling me that running a selection  with `shift+enter` is not possible to execute in an active terminal which runs ipython? All right. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have solved it myself:
Adding this

    `"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["m","IPython","--no-autoindent"]`

 to the JSON-file will do the job as mentioned in the question from the second comment. I had a JSON-file error which hasn't been marked. That way the code snippet wasn't executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it myself: Adding this

`"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["m","IPython","--no-autoindent"]`

to the JSON-file will do the job as mentioned in the question from the second comment. I had a JSON-file error which hasn't been marked. That way the code snippet wasn't executed. Using an online JSON validator helped me to find that error.